# Network drops eveytime I change my IP

Tags: networking, ip

Every time I change my IP with the command `ifconfig wlp2s0 192.168.132.118` I lose internet connection and the only way to get it back is if I run `sudo service network-manager restart` but then the IP resets to the default. Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

You should know how a machine commonly (always) reaches the internet.

It has a local IP, typically in one of the [RFC 1918-addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918), like 192.168.132.118 is an example of.

Commonly home networks employ the subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 (or in CIDR-notation: /24). This means that everything from 192.168.132.1 to 192.168.132.254 is assumed reachable on the local network.

But to reach something outside the local network, you have to go via a router, that forwards packets for you. This is commonly called a gateway. The gateway has one IP in your local subnet (e.g. directly reachable), and one address in another network, and a routing table specifying how to reach other hosts.

To set a route, use `ip`:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.132.1
```

This of course assumes that your router is reachable at 192.168.132.1. Your router **has** to be in the same subnet as you set your IP to.

But my real question is why you would want to change your IP. You probably don't.

In addition, you may have to set DNS servers to suitable values.